# Why is the NLog not logging as expected?

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying out NLog but have som problems.

Here is the example project : [Sample Link for Project Reference](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DE992A2C8B8C2EC9!8091&authkey=!AKguhVS1d9gQC0c&ithint=file%2Czip)

And theses are the problems :

1. Why am I not getting complete exception in the log fil? No stacktrace?

> Edit : There is a Layout on the target tag that I missed, I added this
>   :
>
> ```
> ${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} | ${stacktrace}
> ```
>
> Now I get a stacktrace but its not complete, its looks like this :
>
> ```
> Control.WndProcException => ThreadContext.OnThreadException => Program.Application_ThreadException
> ```
>
> So no info about the btThrowException_Click where the exception was
>   thrown?

2. Some times it does not log at all? Its like it is cached but never flushed? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=2} ${newline}"
```

By default NLog is doing this "compact" exception. If you add this layout, then you will get full exception with up to 2 levels of inner exceptions.

Regarding the second error, I have never experienced this. Maybe you should provide some more details.